# Typo on https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/posts-by-ids

Tags: bug, api, spelling

In https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/posts-by-ids:

> To find ids *programatically* look for post_id, answer_id, or question_id on post, answer, and question objects respectively.

It should be:

> To find ids **programmatically** look for post_id, answer_id, or question_id on post, answer, and question objects respectively.

Comment: Actually there are [few other typos](https://stackapps.com/q/6899/37357) in the [Documentation page](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs) and the other links

Comment: Also related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/290167/allow-users-to-edit-the-api-documentation

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed now, see @Taryn's answer on [this Stack Apps bug report](https://stackapps.com/a/8543/34061). It now reads

> `{ids}` can contain up to 100 semicolon delimited ids. To find ids programmatically look for `post_id`, `answer_id`, or `question_id` on post, answer, and question objects respectively.